# How to calculate MACs ffor a Neural Network Architecture in using Keras and python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am trying to calculate number of MACs of Neural Network.

Currently I have found this python module
[Flopco](https://github.com/evgps/flopco-keras).

But the problem with it is there is support for "Flatten layer"

```
KeyError: 'Flatten'
```

is there any other module or script available with the support for flatten layer.